# Determine whether the following series that I give is convergent or divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I try to use $p$-series with $b_n=1/2n^{2/3},\; p=2/3 < 1$, so the $p$-series diverges. However, I cannot do the next step with compare the $a_n$ and $b_n$. In this question, $a_n < b_n$, and $b_n$ is divergent not convergent. This situation makes me confuse the comparison rule. I also tried to use the ratio test, the result is lim function = 1, which means use other test.
Please give some details of the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! We'd love to  learn what $a_n$ is …

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{2n+5}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Clearly both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive for $n>0$, so one can use limit comparison test. Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\infty$$and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$ diverges, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$diverges as well (I am assuming that the series you are talking about is the one in your previous question which uses exactly the same wording.).